# jQuery changing attr adds a blank?

Tags: jquery, attr

Trying to change the attr of something, I've got everything working but it adds a blank between the '=' and the 'data' and I really don't know why. I was hoping someone could help me out.

```
function get_delete_news(news_id) {
$.post('remove_get_news.php', {news_id:news_id}, function(data) {
    $('.confirmYes').attr('href', 'remove_news.php?newsID='+data);
});
}
```

So right now it's written out like this: `remove_news.php?newsID= 2`

And I want it to be like this: `remove_news.php?newsID=2`

Comment: Is data a string or integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function will remove leading and trailing whitespace on a string.

Change:

```
$('.confirmYes').attr('href', 'remove_news.php?newsID='+data);
```

to:

```
$('.confirmYes').attr('href', 'remove_news.php?newsID='+data.trim());
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer but am wondering what the value of data is, it seems it should not have whitespace in the first place.

Comment: `$.trim('string')` should be used for crossbrowser compatibility though

Comment: This worked, thank you very much :) Do you have any idea why there is a blank there anyway? It's not coming from the php page.

Comment: If you're positive it's not coming from the PHP page I'm not sure where the space would be introduced from. jQuery doesn't add spaces on its own.

Comment: I'm positive. I even tried the trim in my php without success. Anyway, got it working now so, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently remove_get_news.php is concatenating a space to its response. A workaround would be to do a:

```
data.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
```

before using the data variable.